# Behavior of the improper integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(1+x^2)^t}{e^{(\tan^{-1}x) t}\cosh \left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, asymptotics, improper-integrals

Consider an integral for $t\geq 0$ $$f(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(1+x^2)^t}{e^{(\tan^{-1}x) t}\cosh \left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)}dx\ .$$
**Question-** Prove that $f(t)=\mathcal{O}(e^{c t})$ where $c>0$ is a constant.

I tried: $$f(t)\leq 2\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(1+x)^{2t}}{e^{(\tan^{-1}x) t}\left(e^{\frac{\pi x}{2}}+e^{-\frac{\pi x}{2}}\right)}dx   $$
So we have
$$f(t)\leq 2\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(1+x)^{2t}.e^{ -\frac{\pi x}{2}  }}{e^{(\tan^{-1}x) t}\left(1+e^{-\pi x}\right)}dx   $$
I am struggling to prove the required asymptotic. You help will be appreciated.

Comment: @sadman-ncc Thanks for the edit. Please give a hint to solve the problem.

Comment: @sadman-ncc: Do not use `\displaystyle` in titles, compare https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/42969

Comment: Upon further simplification, it becomes $$\dfrac{\left(x+1\right)^{2t} e^{\frac{{\pi}x}{2}-t\arctan\left(x\right)}}{e^{{\pi}x}+1}.$$ All I could do so far.

Comment: @MartinR Can you please try the question?

Comment: Numerically I'm getting $\ln f(t) \sim c t\ln t$. It's possible the trouble you're having proving this comes from it being false. Perhaps that was supposed to be $\cosh(\pi x t/2)$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog Thanks. How are you getting the result numerically? When we have $\cosh (\pi x t/2)$, then is the result $f(t)=O(e^{c t})$ true?

Comment: I just had Mathematica evaluate it for me at high $t$. Also it's probably not $\cosh(\pi x t/2)$, as then the integral is $O(t^{-1})$. Which I suppose *is* $O(e^{c t})$, but in a kind of trivial sense.

Comment: @eyeballfrog So is the claim in the question incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x>0$, we have $\tan^{-1}x \le \pi/2$ and $\exp(x)\ge \cosh(x)$. Thus, $\exp[\pi/2(t +x)]\ge \exp(t \tan^{-1}x)\cosh(\pi x /2)$ and we have
$$
f(t) \ge \int_0^\infty (1+x^2)^te^{-(\pi/2)(t+x)}dx\ge e^{-\pi t /2}\int_0^\infty x^{2t}e^{-\pi x/2}dx  = \frac{2}{\pi}\left(\frac{2}{\pi e^{\pi/4}}\right)^{2t}\Gamma(2t+1)
$$
From Stirling's approximation, we know that $\Gamma(n+1)\ge(n/e)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}$, which gives
$$
f(t)\ge \frac{4}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sqrt{t}\left(k t\right)^{2t}
$$
where $k = (4/\pi)e^{-(1+\pi/4)}$. $(kt)^{2t}\notin O(e^{c t})$ for any $c$, so the statement is false.

Now for a further challenge: the numerical evaluation suggests $f(t) \in O(\sqrt{t}(kt)^{2t})$. Can you prove this?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sorry, I cannot prove that $f(t)\in O(\sqrt{t} (kt)^{2t})$. Please help me to prove this

Comment: Of no use, but  $$\int_0^\infty (1+x^2)^te^{-(\pi/2)(t+x)}dx$$ express in terms of Bessel and Struve functions. By the way, nice solution and $\to +1$. Cheers :-)